# Are eDP driver boards compatible between resolutions?

Tags: display, lvds

I'm looking at various eDP to HDMI controller boards that are available. The ones that I've found identify a very specific resolution: 1920x1080 or 1366x768, etc.

If I buy a controller board for 1920x1080, can I hook it up to an eDP panel that is a lower resolution? Or do I need a board that specifically matches that resolution.

I do understand that some panels require a different number of pins and wires; 1-lane or 2-lane, 30 or 40 pin, etc. This question is not about the cable but the driver board and panel mating once a compatible cable has been used.

Comment: refer to the controller board datasheet